# What is the meaning of ngx_http_request_s::exten

Tags: nginx

I want to know the meaning of the `exten`, which is one member of the structure `ngx_http_request_t`, also, `ngx_http_set_exten` hopes to be excavated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it means *file extension*, being the part of the final path element that follows a period. It is used to lookup the MIME type in the [types](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#types) data structure, to be used in the response.

Relevant code [is here](http://lxr.nginx.org/source/src/http/ngx_http_core_module.c). Line 1701.